# what ram can I buy for my linux PC

Tags: memory

I have an old PC - 2011 I think. It only has 4gb of ram and I'd like to buy more because it keeps maxing out and hanging.

I took out the 1 stick of RAM that was in there already and checked out the info on it but it's not what I was expecting after watching a couple of vids and reading a couple of tutorials. I guess because it's quite old.

If I type in the details into amazon or google, the results aren't exactly the same, and the closest are not in stock (again - maybe too old?)

4gb 2rx8 pc3-10600u-9-11-b0

Is what I have. Just one of them. There's another slot. Can I upgrade to something more modern, or do I need to get exactly the same (eg 4gb 2rx8 pc3-10600u-9-11-b0) model?

Thanks

**EDIT** - on the sticker on the RAM

```
MT16JTF51264AZ-1G4D1
4GB 2RX8 PC3-10600U-9-11-B0
PRODUCT OF CHINA       DP AAZ1N009
```

The Processor:

```
Intel© Core™ i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 4
```

Comment: When you say more modern, what exactly do you mean, your system only supports the same revision of DDR you currently are using (unclear if you have DDR2 or DDR3).

Comment: I can't attach the pic of the RAM I took, but there's no mention of DDR on it at all. How do I find out what type of ram it is? DDR2 or DDR3?

Comment: Provide the full part number on the sticker on the module, or pull the current module out of the system, and look at the pin layout yourself (Wikipedia has helpful pictures to perform this task).  You could also identify the processor.  All information should go in the question instead of a comment

Comment: I appreciate your help. Question edited

Comment: 4gb? Maxing it out using Linux as a "regular" user?  something isn't right here.  If you really have 4gb... ask yourself "where is my ram going?"

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas how do I find out? I check out system monitor and the RAM and swap are always near 100%

Comment: On a linux system, every last bit of free memory is used as a disk cache.  Freaked me out the first time I saw it too.  Rather than looking at free, sort by memory use.  You will probably see that there aren't any programs hogging it all.   Or perhaps you will.. problem still solved.

Comment: @user1113001 - You have not clarified what you mean by "something more modern".

Comment: @Ramhound - when I saw that there was no 'DDR' at all on the sticker. I assumed it was RAM from a previous generation or something. I know nothing about RAM and assumed perhaps PC3 was the previous incarnation of RAM

Comment: @user1113001 - I looked up the part number.  You still have not clarified your question.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - thanks for the input. I'm not completely sure what you mean though. I've no knowledge about hardware really. Basically the problem I'm trying to solve is to make my computer faster. And I noticed via system_monitor that the resources graph for swap and RAM are usually close to 100% even when I turn the computer on fresh.

If I click into processes and sort by memory, then the top of the list is firefox, cinnamon, and a bunch of 'web content' records. What are they? I've only firefox open and 20 tabs. 

Have I some crap running on my computer that I don't know about?

Comment: @Ramhound - I'm sorry, I think I'm confused. Probably "something more modern" doesn't matter. I assumed I'd an old version of hardware, but Christopher Hostage tells me in his answer that: ""PC3-10600" means that it's DDR3 running at 10600 MHz"

Comment: What make and model motherboard do you have?

Answer (score 1):

"PC3-10600" means that it's DDR3 running at 10600 MHz.
Find the motherboard make/model and look up what its maximum supported RAM is.  Your CPU is 64-bit.  Ensure that your OS is also 64-bit, or it won't be able to use more than 4 GB.

You can find matched pairs of RAM sticks cheaply for sale, or ask local businesses or schools if they have spare they're discarding.  You may be able to mix-and-match RAM with various speeds, but I've found that getting a matched set works best.  At best, a mixed set of RAM sticks will operate at the slower rated speed.

You mentioned "maxing out and hanging" in the original question.  Linux has a robust memory system, so there is probably another cause to the hanging.  More memory probably won't hurt, however.